# Mouse cursor doesn't move while scroll wheel is clicked down

Tags: 22.04, mouse, xfce, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I've had an issue ever since I recovered my system from a missing-X11 state where clicking down on the scroll wheel prevents the mouse cursor from moving. I don't know what mouse settings I changed, but I modified a few of them to get my mouse moving at a reasonable speed.

The functionality I **currently have** is:

- Mouse moves at a reasonable speed
- Clicking the scroll wheel stops the mouse movement, and continuous mouse movement makes a page scroll

The functionality I **want to have** is:

- Mouse moves at a reasonable speed
- Clicking the scroll wheel keeps mouse movement, and mouse movement makes the page scroll

Any suggestions appreciated ~

Comment: Try updating the kernel, it is something wrong with mouse driver.

Comment: please [edit] your question with more detail about what you changed. In `Settings > Mouse & Touchpad` there are precious few setting to change...